# How can I check for a specific amount of items in a player's inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map and I was wondering if there was a command block command that can check for 8 nautilus shells in a players inventory.

Answer (score 1):

```
/execute if data entity @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:nautilus_shell",Count:8b}]}
```